# Watching a global variable / boolean expression for changes

Tags: c++, assembly

I was wondering how could I do something when some boolean expression becomes true. I can't use a simple `if`, because I want that it checks when the bools expressions changes in any part of code and do it if it is true.

It would be something like this:

```
when(int x != 0)
{
  cout << "x";
}
```

It could use Assembly to, the better the performance the best.

Comment: Are you looking for `if`?

Comment: No. C'mon I would not bother you for something like this

Comment: Ok, so... what is your question? And why assembly would perform better? Better than what?

Comment: Just in case: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: you are definitely looking for `if`. There is no alternative to a conditional branch - you can work around the actual keyword but it will still result in a conditional branch. I dont think you should bother yourself with assembler right now, you still need to learn much .... just saying --- ASM is for advanced programmers or electronics engineering students.

Comment: I made an edit. I don't want `if`

Comment: Depending on your environment (that you forgot to specify) you could use a hardware memory write breakpoint.

Comment: How do I do this? if you meant IDE when you sad environment, I'm using CodeBlocks

Comment: there is nothing else - because `if` is the most basic logic construct (read : "conditional branch"), wanting to abandon it would result in an impossible logical state - you cant write (useful) applications without it. I recommend reading a good book about IT basics.

Comment: I think you didn't undertood my question. I know the basics and I know this. What I'm trying to do is something usind `if` and other stuff to achieve the result I wish.

Comment: you're constantly contradicting yourself

Comment: "C++/Assembly" that's a new one

Comment: thats like "computer / banana" or something :-)

Comment: No it means that I want to use one of the following: C++ or Assembly

Comment: even the operator "or" does not make any sense if it comes to these two languages, ASM is/are machine instruction sets (with mnemonics), C is a human-readable language and ... to be honest : you wont be able to write ASM code with your level of knowledge. Sorry but its like that.

Comment: Currently it's asking how to do exactly what `if` does in the title. If you want to run code when a variable changes, then put that in the title.

Comment: Ok... I edit somethigs. Can you undertand now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering how could I do something when some boolean expression is true

That's exactly what `if` does.

> I want that it checks when the bools expressions changes in any part of code

Simply use `if` every time you assign the variable.

Of course, when you always do the same check after assigning the variable and do the same thing if the check is true, then you clearly have repetition. When you want to repeatedly do the same thing multiple times, you can use a function to avoid repeating the code. Just don't accidentally modify the variable directly instead of calling that function.

Here's an example of a function that assigns a variable in memory and does a branch based on a boolean expression. If `true`, it prints the variable:

```
                    .cfi_startproc
                    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 8
                    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
0000 00482DE9       stmfd   sp!, {fp, lr}
                    .save {fp, lr}

                .LCFI0:

                    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
                    .cfi_offset 11, -8
                    .cfi_offset 14, -4
                    .setfp fp, sp, #4
0004 04B08DE2       add fp, sp, #4

                .LCFI1:

                    .cfi_def_cfa 11, 4
                    .pad #8
0008 08D04DE2       sub sp, sp, #8
000c 08000BE5       str r0, [fp, #-8]

0010 30309FE5       ldr r3, .L3
0014 08201BE5       ldr r2, [fp, #-8]
0018 002083E5       str r2, [r3, #0]

001c 24309FE5       ldr r3, .L3
0020 003093E5       ldr r3, [r3, #0]
0024 000053E3       cmp r3, #0
0028 0400001A       bne .L1           ; <-- the branch is here

002c 14309FE5       ldr r3, .L3
0030 003093E5       ldr r3, [r3, #0]
0034 10009FE5       ldr r0, .L3+4
0038 0310A0E1       mov r1, r3
003c FEFFFFEB       bl  printf

                .L1:

0040 04D04BE2       sub sp, fp, #4
0044 0088BDE8       ldmfd   sp!, {fp, pc}

                .L4:

                    .align  2

                .L3:

0048 00000000       .word   global
004c 00000000       .word   .LC0
                    .cfi_endproc
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is for debugging, set a data-breakpoint, or watch-point, on `x` in your debugger.

If not, then you're using C++, so you can wrap `x` in a class that overloads the assignment operator to prints changes.  Overload `operator const &int()` to allow stuff like `foo = x + 4`, without needing `foo = x.get_value() + 4`.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class value_changelogger
{
  private:
    T m_val;
  public:
    T& operator=(T newval) {
      if (newval != m_val)
        std::cout << newval << std::endl;
      return m_val = newval;
    }
    operator const T&() { return m_val; }  // only allow const-references to escape our watchful eye
};

value_changelogger<int> x;

int main(int, char**)
{
    x = 4;
    int y = x + 4;
    x = y;
    // x++;  doesn't compile: no operator++ overload, and non-const operator T&() isn't overloaded.
}
```

([wandbox link](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/52Q0SFNzw4ForV2J))

[C++11 explicit operator T&](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8059110/224132) doesn't appear to help for change-detection without actually having code for all the modify operators.

So I think you'd have to individually overload all the operators that can modify the value, to have this fully transparent.

Note that this is just syntactic sugar to add in an `if ()` check everywhere `x` is assigned.  **It doesn't make the machine code any more efficient** than if you'd gone and manually done that, like you'd have to in C.

Comment: I'm sure someone's written a complete wrapper for integer types somewhere... altho can't seem to find it by googling

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly possible with C++, because all statements are executed sequentially. There is no "C++ data breakpoint", like debuggers offer it.

Assuming you don't want to change all the places where the variable is changed, the closest you can get is to create a second thread that repeatedly checks the boolean condition, and executes the action when the condition is met. But the action will never be executed immediately after the condition has changed, there will always be a short delay.

Comment: Using threads is a good idea. I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
int _x;
inline int get_X(){return _x;}
inline int set_X(int value){
    _x = value;
    //dosomething
    return _x;
}
```

and then instead of writing `x = bla` in your code, write `set_X(bla)`.

Comment: I'll try it. I don't know this commands. Could you explain then(I mean `get` and `set`)

Comment: @RafaelMarinho this are implicite get or set methods so you can say `X = 5` instead of `set_X(5)`

Comment: Ok. I got the point.

Comment: @AntiHeadshot They are.. In C#. This question is about C++, and the example you posted contains invalid syntax for C++.

Comment: @specializt I didn't say that it won't use if.

Comment: yes you did. Multiple times.

Comment: @specializt the main questin was `I want that it checks when the bools expressions changes in any part of code`

Comment: @specializt No, what i sad is that what I want is not `if`. I could use `if`, but alone it couldn't reach what I want.

Comment: @AntiHeadshot that is it

Comment: @RafaelMarinho You are wellcome!

Comment: @AntiHeadshot This guys can't undertand the question and just downvote because of then ignorance.

Comment: both of you : please go and read about the term "conditional branch". You both are making this more ridiculous than it should be. This answer is a decorated `if`, nothing less and nothing more. Its also apparently not C or C++

Comment: @RafaelMarinho I already explained my downvote. The code snippet given by the answerer is in C#, while the question is about C++/assembly. The code that is given is not valid C++ syntax.

Comment: @specializt >.< you are right, itx C# I overlooked that part

Comment: It is an example of what I want. I know that it is not allowed in c++.

Comment: @RafaelMarinho you can do the same in c++ just with a different syntax.

Comment: @specializt fixed language, for sure its a 'decoraded' `if` but it will check any time it changes, without him having to pay any attention to it.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I want

Comment: that is also usually called "listener", you're basically re-inventing the wheel : https://schneide.wordpress.com/2008/12/08/observerlistener-structures-in-c-with-boosts-smart-pointers/

Comment: @specializt `with boost’s smart pointers` I think it's more like using a wheel instead of a reinforced aluminum wheel

Comment: that .... doesnt make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: @specializt one is known to work, the other maybe is overengineered for this task

Comment: re-inventing the wheel is pretty much the exact opposite of "known to work". In facts thats the definition -- something which is proven and distributed. Your personal experimentation will probably remain private and noone will "know it to work".

Comment: @specializt using get and set methods for this kind of task is common not `personal experimentation`.

Comment: yes, because its very simple and has to work everytime **unless** you introduce multithreading -- and suddenly everything isnt _"proven"_ anymore ;). I could go on -- but lets just say that simple solutions only work for simple environments.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: I added an answer with C++ operator overloading, instead of forcing all the source code using `x` to be modified to use accessor functions like this is suggesting.  (regardless of what syntax).  Overloading operators changes the meaning of the other code, so it generates different asm from the same source, because `x` is now a class type with overloaded operators.